# Retrieving data: Firebase and Swift 3 issue

Tags: firebase, swift3, firebase-realtime-database

Good Morning. I have been building an app for a group of teachers friends of mine, but I am new in programming Swift 3 and even more in Firebase, but I am trying and studying a lot. I have also done extensive research online before posting here, but most are outdated or not specifically about this question. so I hope someone could help me. I have some data at Firebase and I can show them in a table view controller, the way I wanted to. When I want to see some more details about one row – where I have some information about student’s validations (each row for each student) – I click on that cell and I have a new view controller with these details (detail view controller). What I cannot retrieve, is the photo of that student (image URL), that is correctly stored in Firebase, but in another node:

```
---root    
   ---2017FirstSemester
       --validationA
          -- key: -Kwteywgwueyuye
            -- name: Paul Newman
            -- note: 9,0
            -- date: 12/12/2016
            -- teacher: Anne
          -- key: -Kwieiwe86he
            -- name: Barbara Eden
            -- note: 7,9
            -- date: 12/12/2016
            -- teacher: Mark
          -- (…)
        -- (…)
   -- Students
          -- key: -KweewojPaulNewman            
            -- name: Paul Newman
            -- imageURL:  “https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/…”
        (UPDATED)
```

This is part of the code:

```
import Foundation
import Firebase

/// UPDATED SOLUTUON    
var ImagemURL_G: String?

struct Students {

    var name: String?
    var imageURL: String?
    var key: String!


    init(name: String, key: String = "", imageURL: String) {
        self.name = name
        self.imageURL  = imageURL
        self.key = key
    }

    init(snapshot: FIRDataSnapshot) {
        key = snapshot.key
        let snapshotValue = snapshot.value as! [String: AnyObject]
        name = snapshotValue["name"] as? String
        imageURL = snapshotValue["imageURL"] as? String

        /// UPDATED SOLUTUON    
        ImagemURL_G: = imagemURL

    }

    func toAnyObject() -> Any {
        return [
            "name": name,
            "userKey": key,
            "imageURL": imageURL
        ]
    }
}
```

Detail View Controller:

```
import Foundation
import UIKit
import Firebase

class DetailStudent: UIViewController {

    var DescFB: Students!


@IBOutlet weak var imgPhoto: UIImageView!
@IBOutlet weak var labelStudentName: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var labelTeacher: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var labelNote: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var labelDate: UILabel!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    labelStudentName.text = DescFB.name
    labelTeacher.text = DescFB.teacher
    labelNote.text = DescFB.note
    labelDate.text = DescFB.date

    LoadStudent()

    }

func LoadStudent() {

let nameIns = labelStudentName.text
let ref = FIRDatabase.database().reference().child("2017FirstSemester ").child(“validationA”)

    let db = ref.queryOrdered(byChild: "name").queryEqual(toValue: nomeIns)
        db.observe(.value, with: { (snapshot) in
            for snap in snapshot.children {

          print("userKey: \((snap as! FIRDataSnapshot).key)")
          self.labelKeyResult.text = (snap as! FIRDataSnapshot).key
          print("PRINT SNAP: \(snap)")
            }
        })
}
```

When the details view controller loads, it loads all the value of the validations and I try to use the student name (that comes through segue) to reference a new method to bring the student`s information from “Students” node (where the information name and image photo are stored to be used in other view controller for other validations or other purposes), but I can just retrieve “key” information to show it in a label object. “Name” and “imageURL” I could just find a way to see them printed in debugger window, as show below:

```
userKey: -K_GiQwPXfR3AMvxyBat

PRINT SNAP: Snap (-K_GiQwPXfR3AMvxyBat) {
    imageURL = "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/chklist-5f5d3.appspot.com/o/https:%2Fchklist-...b36b3";
    name = "PAUL NEWMAN";
    userKey = "-K_GiQwPXfR3AMvxyBat";
}
```

I need that string from "imageURL" to show these photo in a image view object and retrieve this string is what I don't know how to do it:

```
var url = DescFB.imageURL
let url2 = NSURL(string: (url)!)
let data = NSData(contentsOf: (url2 as? URL)!)
imgPhoto.image = UIImage(data: data as! Data)
```

Inside "func LoadStudent" I have tried a lot of different ways and codes and nothing. I think it is very close to the right solution, but I could not see it. I hope someone can find it and help me. Thank you very much and Happy 2017.

/// UPDATED: PART OF SOLUTION

```
func LoadStudent() {

        let nomeIns = labelStudentName.text
        var newTeste: [Students] = []
        let db = refImagem.queryOrdered(byChild: "name").queryEqual(toValue: nomeIns)
        db.observe(.value, with: { (snapshot) in

            for resposta in snapshot.children {
                let itemsAadicionar = Students(snapshot: resposta as! FIRDataSnapshot)
                newTeste.append(itemsAadicionar)
            }

            self.AlunosAvaliados = newTeste

            // It's here where the url receive URL string captured before
            var url = ImagemURL_G
            if url != nil{
                let url2 = NSURL(string: (url)!)
                let data = NSData(contentsOf: (url2 as? URL)!)
                if data != nil {
                    self.imgPhoto.image = UIImage(data: data as! Data) }
            }else{
                url = "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/chklist-5f5d3.appspot.com/o/imagesAlunos%2Fpessoa2.png?alt=media&token=e4b47dca-9dd0-444e-81d5-cf4cf122b94a"
                let url2 = NSURL(string: (url)!)
                let data = NSData(contentsOf: (url2 as? URL)!)
                self.imgPhoto.image = UIImage(data: data as! Data)
            }

        })

    }
```

Comment: Can you check your Firebase structure? The Students node looks a little wonky. I would think you would have a Students node with children that have keys generated by childByAutoId and children of those each being a specific student with their student info. There also appears to be a disconnect between the data in the validation node and the student node.

Comment: @Frank maybe I have written it wrong. I will do it again. Anyway, it looks like, thinking comparing with an MS Access data structure, different tables that has a relationship. The first one, Students, have their personal data; and the others, validationA - for exemple - has the data from an specifically validation. There are some others. The Students node is directly connected to the root and I think it doesn't change the way I need to retrieve the imageURL. I have it in my retrieving snapshot. I just cannot make it comes to a String. I guess.

Comment: I don't know if this is the best way, but i did it: 1) I have defined a global variable to capture the string for the URL, for any view controller: `var ImagemURL_G: String?`. 2) Inside struct "Students", I have set this variable to capture the string just below the snapshot for it: `ImagemURL_G = imageURL`. 3) I have rewritten the LoadStudent method. I will publish it as an update after main question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know if this is the best way, but i have found one way

1) I have defined a global variable to capture the string for the URL, for any view controller: `var ImagemURL_G: String?`.

2) Inside struct "Students", I have set this variable to capture the string just below the snapshot for it: `ImagemURL_G = imageURL`. ImageURL is one of the components of an array, so I tried to capture the string here, after the array was populated only with one student, that I have define inside LoadStudent method: `queryEqual(toValue: nomeIns)`

3) I have rewritten the LoadStudent method to use this string captured inside struct "Students" and converted the NSData back to UIImage.

It worked. If someone can do in a better and simple way, I appreciate to see it published here. I guess this is not the best way, but to my level of experience in Swift 3 and Firebase this will be the one, for while.